# Understanding of Zorn's Lemma

Tags: set-theory

*Zorn's Lemma.* Suppose a partially ordered set $P$ has the property that every chain (i.e. totally ordered subset) has an upper bound in $P$. Then the set $P$ contains at least one maximal element.

My question is that why partially ordered, why not well-ordered?

Comment: Try to see that the "partially ordered" statement implies the "well ordered" statement, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every well-order is a partial order and thus Zorn's Lemma holds for well-ordered sets (in which every subset has an upper bound) as well. However, these sets always contain a maximum (namely, the upper bound for the whole set) and thus Zorn's Lemma is trivial in these cases. By the same argument, Zorn's Lemma is trivial for linear orders.

Comment: @hayyam You are very welcome!

Comment: @Stefan How do we know that all well-ordered sets necessarily contain a maximum? $\mathbb{R}$ is well-ordered, but it does not have a maximum.

Comment: @sequence First, the standard order on $\mathbb{R}$ is not a well-order. Second, the standard order on $\mathbb{R}$ has subsets (which trivially are totally ordered, because we are talking about a total order here) with no upper bound (like $\mathbb{R}$). Hence Zorn's Lemma doesn't apply. I hope this clarifies things ;-)